# import css still stays in page when route changes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router

I am using two main layouts with react router like below. I have written AppRoute component to use different layouts with switch.

Problem is when i come back to "/" home from "/login" or "/register" route some import css related to "LayoutLoginRegister" still stays in browser. So it breaks the page. Because this css belongs to "LayoutLoginRegister" not "LayoutLanding"

**App.js**

```
 const AppWrapper = styled.div`
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100%;
`;

const AppRoute = ({ component: Component, layout: Layout, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => (
      <Layout>
        <Component {...props} />
      </Layout>
    )}
  />
);

AppRoute.propTypes = {
  component: React.PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  layout: React.PropTypes.any.isRequired,
};


export default function App() {
  return (
    <AppWrapper>
      <Helmet
        titleTemplate="%s - React.js Boilerplate"
        defaultTitle="React.js Boilerplate"
      >
        <meta name="description" content="A React.js Boilerplate application" />
      </Helmet>
      <Switch>
        <AppRoute exact path="/" layout={LayoutLanding} component={HomePage} />
        <AppRoute path="/features" layout={LayoutLanding} component={FeaturePage} />
        <AppRoute path="/login" layout={LayoutLoginRegister} component={LoginPage} />
        <AppRoute path="/register" layout={LayoutLoginRegister} component={RegisterPage} />
      </Switch>
    </AppWrapper>
  );
}
```

**LayoutLoginRegister Layout**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './LayoutLoginRegister.scss';

export class LayoutLoginRegister extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

LayoutLoginRegister.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default LayoutLoginRegister;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing CSS with webpack in this way will not load / unload the css when the component mounts / unmounts.

I would recommend namespacing your css styles, because you are using scss & separate files for your layouts, this should be fairly easy.

Wrap the contents of LayoutLoginRegister.scss with

```
.component-LayoutLoginRegister {
    [layout login styles go here]
}
```

Then add a class to your LayoutLoginRegister component

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="component-LayoutLoginRegister">
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
}
```

The CSS will remain loaded, but it will not affect anything other than your LayoutLoginRegister component.

If you need to apply styles to something shared, like `<body>`
You can add a class to the body / HTML element when a component mounts / unmounts.

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        document.body.classList.add('MyComponent-mounted');
    }

    componentDidUnmount() {
        document.body.classList.remove('MyComponent-mounted');
    }
}
```

Although I would generally avoid this unless absolutely necessary, as it couples your component with document.body and makes the component unpure, harder to reuse, etc.

Comment: Thank you for solution. This way i can achieve the desired result.